# how to calculate some numbers in table with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

need a help with a table calculate some numbers with jquery

The calculations are done correctly for first table row and tfoot for equal is working fine

Monthly Quantity*unit Price=Total Monthly
Total Annually=Total Monthly*12

the table foot each td is adding above column td
the example:

```js
$("html").bind('input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup', function() {
  $('table tr td:nth-child(5) input,table tr td:nth-child(6) input').prop('readonly', true);

  var qntMonthly = Number($('table tr td:nth-child(3) input').val());
  var unitprice = Number($('table tr td:nth-child(4) input').val());
  var totalmonthly = qntMonthly * unitprice;
  var totalannualy = totalmonthly * 12;


  document.querySelector('table tr td:nth-child(5) input').value = qntMonthly * unitprice;
  document.querySelector('table tr td:nth-child(6) input').value = totalannualy;


  var alltotalmonthly = 0;
  $("table tbody tr td:nth-child(3) input").each(function() {
    alltotalmonthly += +$(this).val();
  });
  var allunits = 0;
  $("table tbody tr td:nth-child(4) input").each(function() {
    allunits += +$(this).val();
  });
  var totalallmonthly = 0;
  $("table tbody tr td:nth-child(5) input").each(function() {
    totalallmonthly += +$(this).val();
  });
  var totalallannualy = 0;
  $("table tbody tr td:nth-child(6) input").each(function() {
    totalallannualy += +$(this).val();
  });

  /*document.querySelector('table tfoot tr td:nth-child(3)').html(alltotalmonthly);*/
  document.getElementById("allqutymonthly").innerHTML = alltotalmonthly
  document.getElementById("allunits").innerHTML = allunits
  document.getElementById("totalallmonthly").innerHTML = totalallmonthly
  document.getElementById("totalallannualy").innerHTML = totalallannualy

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableA table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>no.</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>Monthly Quantity</th>
      <th>unit Price</th>
      <th>Total Monthly</th>
      <th>Total Annually</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">1</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="Tea" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" value="2" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" value="2" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" value="" class="form-control">

      </td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" value="" class="form-control"></td>
      <td class="text-center">

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">2</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="coffee" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" value="10" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" value="3" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" value="5" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" value="2" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>



  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="text-center">Total</td>
      <td>
        <div id="allqutymonthly" class="totalSum">00000</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="allunits" class="totalSum">00000</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="totalallmonthly" class="totalSum">00000</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="totalallannualy" class="totalSum">00000</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

1- I want to apply it to all table rows

2- I need the total number Appears automatically when the page is opened and the total number change directly.

Comment: Loop through each row and use document.ready https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: thanks ,how to use document.ready with $("html").bind ?

Comment: Replace `$("html").bind('input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup', function() {` with `$(function() {` - you said how to have to run on startup, so why do you need an event handler?  (also, `bind` was deprecated over 8 years ago)

Comment: bind not working now , it is important to change total number directly

Comment: You asked for - "*I need the total number Appears automatically when the page is opened*" - if you have **other requirements**, please add them to the question.

Comment: sorry  , i edit it

Comment: can you help with update code ?